# What reasons are there for using Arrays instead of Objects to store lists other than helper functions?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

### TL:DR

Beside the use of the convent Array helper functions (which I could theoretically create for objects), and considering the performance advantage of Object lookups, what reason could be given to use an Array instead of an Object?

### Objects

From what I understand, because JavaScript objects use hash tables to lookup their key -> data pairs, the look-up time, no matter the length of the object is very small.

For example if I want a really fast dictionary look up, in the past I've (and we can condense the syntax but that's besides the point) stored dictionary data in JSON as

```
"apple" : "apple",
```

and then used

```
if (Dictionary.apple) console.log("Yep it's a word!");
```

And the result return very very fast regardless of whether my dictionary contains 30,000 words or 300,000.

### Arrays

On the other hand, unless I know the number an array item is attached to, I have to loop through the entire array, causing larger lookup times the further the item is down the list.

The good thing I know of about using an array is that I get access to convenient functions such as `slice`, but these could probably be created for use with objects.

### My Question

So, considering the lookup efficiency of objects, I'd currently choose an object over an array for every situation. But I could easily be wrong about this.

**Beside the use of the convent Array helper functions (which I could theoretically create for objects), and considering the performance advantage of Object lookups, what reason could be given to use an Array instead of an Object?**

Comment: What "performance advantage" of object lookups are you talking about? Object lookup is object lookup; there's no difference between arrays and plain objects in that respect. Your premise is simply incorrect.

Comment: Objects for if you just need to store data, arrays for if you need to store data *in order*.

Comment: Arrays are objects in JS.

Comment: @Pointy because I can know which Object property name to lookup, and get that result instantly, while arrays only store the data with numbered keys, so I have to loop through to find the array item.

Comment: Changing the internal structure of an object has a performance cost. So if you want to sort/filter an object, and have an object as the result, it'll be slower than an array, since you'll have to 'change' the object searched or create new properties in a new object, for each iteration. If your array contains simple data, you can use `array.indexOf('element')` to get the index and have almost the same speed as an object lookup, without the need for a loop.

Comment: @BrianGlaz yes and no, Arrays are keyed differently than Objects, they are objects, but they have a different key structure. My examples explain my question, did you read it?

Comment: "On the other hand, unless I know the number an array item is attached to, I have to loop through the entire array" Same for an object.. what if you don't know what key you want?

Comment: @JonathanTodd They could be keyed the same.. `var obj = {0: 'a', 1:'b'}` is a valid object.

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing apples to oranges here. If you need to map from arbitrary string keys to values, as in your example with "apple", then you use an object. (In ES2015, you *might* alternatively use a Map instance.)

If you have a whole bunch of oranges, and you want to keep them in a  list numbered from 0, you put the oranges in an array and index by which (numbered) orange you want.

The process of locating a property on an object is the same whether the object is a plain Object instance or an Array instance. In modern JavaScript runtime environments, it's safe to assume that the process for looking up number-indexed array properties is appropriately optimized to be even faster than the hash lookup for arbitrary string-named properties. That, however, is a completely separate issue from the nature of the work you need to do and the choice of data structure. Either you have a list of things, such that the order of the things in the list is the salient relationship between them, or you have *named* things that you need to access by those names. The two situations are conceptually different.

Comment: So even if I apply numbered keys as object property names and looped through the object (with structure identical to an array), the object would be looped through slower, not being optimized for this?

Comment: @JonathanTodd no, no, no, no.  If you're looking for items **by name**, then you've simply chosen the wrong abstraction if you pack the objects into a list. It's not really an "objects vs. arrays" issue in any intrinsic sense; the choice completely depends on the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Having numbers as keys in an object to use it as a pseudo array is just silly, since you lose all the methods of the array and gain (almost) nothing.

Comment: @JonathanTodd in Java, for example, there's a family of different abstractions: Collections, Lists, Maps, Sets, etc. All have different properties and are used to handle different sorts of data models; it doesn't make sense to compare one vs. the other as being generally better or worse.

Answer (score 0):

One big difference is the order of elements.

Looping through objects keys can't guarantee any specific order.
Looping through array keys will always give you the same order of elements.